# RecyclierView's notifyItemInserted does not work with arrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I have 1 ArrayList and 1 RecyclerView. Data from DB are retrieved and stored in the ArrayList for displaying in the RecyclerView. All the things work fine with adding new item to the RecyclerView, but without the adding animation. I know I should use notifyItemInserted for the adding animation, but it didn't work. No inserting animation was appearing. Now I have to go back to the previous page and then get in the page again so that the added item was showing. So, how to add back the inserting animation?

Any help will be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Code to pass the data and set the adapter:

```
 db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    dbList = new ArrayList<>();
    dbList = db.getFilteredItems();

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

    //newest to oldest order (database stores from oldest to newest)
    llm.setReverseLayout(true);
    llm.setStackFromEnd(true);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
    mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this, llm, dbList);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Code to retrieve data from DB:

```
 //retrieve filtered data from DB
public List<AudioItem> getFilteredItems(){
    List<AudioItem> audioList = new ArrayList<>();
    String titleName = EditActivity.titleName;
    String query = "select * from " + TABLE_NAME + " where " + COLUMN_NAME_RECORDING_NAME + " like '" + titleName + "%'";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            AudioItem audio = new AudioItem();
            audio.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            audio.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            audio.setFilePath(cursor.getString(2));
            audio.setLength(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)));
            audio.setTime(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(4)));
            audioList.add(audio);

        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        cursor.close();
    }

    return audioList;
}
```

Code to insert data into the DB:

```
/* Insert data into database */
public void addRecording(String recordingName, String filePath, long length) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COLUMN_NAME_RECORDING_NAME, recordingName);
    cv.put(COLUMN_NAME_RECORDING_FILE_PATH, filePath);
    cv.put(COLUMN_NAME_RECORDING_LENGTH, length);
    cv.put(COLUMN_NAME_TIME_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis());
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
    db.close();

    if (mOnDatabaseChangedListener != null) {
        mOnDatabaseChangedListener.onNewDatabaseEntryAdded();
    }
}
```

Code to invoke the inserting animation:

```
 @Override
public void onNewDatabaseEntryAdded() {
    //item added to top of the list
    Log.e("Count: ", Integer.toString(getItemCount()));
   // notifyDataSetChanged();
    notifyItemInserted(getItemCount());
    //llm.scrollToPosition(getItemCount() - 1);
}
```

Comment: Some code would help us help you.

Comment: @nukeforum code snippets added. Thanks

Comment: @KenWong, Why you are using 2 arraylist when you can do it with single arraylist also, you can pass titleName as parameter in getDataFromDB method and then by executing like query you can fetch data and return it

Comment: @Vickyexpert oh, that's my mistake. I make it as one ArrayList now, but there's still no RecyclerView's insert animation

Comment: Update your above code so can check exact issue and help you to resolve it'

Comment: @Vickyexpert code and question updated. Please check it out. Thank you so much.

Comment: use adapter.notifyItemInserted(getItemCount() - 1);, it will help

Comment: @Vickyexpert I put it under the setAdapter function, but it didn't work. I still have to refresh the page by myself :-(

Comment: @KenWong it may be possible your method onNewDatabaseEntryAdded() is not calling from DB class, so try to call this line just after you are calling this method addRecordings, from your activity

Comment: @Vickyexpert it didn't work as well :-((((

Answer (score 0):

If you make a new `ArrayList` every time something changes and assign it to a new adapter and assign that new adapter to the `RecyclerView`, wonky things happen.

You should break the `ArrayList`s out into a Model type of object or integrate them into your current DB model object. If you do this, you can simply update `itemlist` and the changes will be reflected in your `RecyclerView`.

Here's some pseudo code since I don't really have much of your code to work off of:

```
public class DataModel {
  private ArrayList<Foo> itemlist = new ArrayList<>();

  public DataModel(){}
  public ArrayList<Foo> getItemList() { return itemlist; }
}

public class YourActivity extends Activity {
  private DataModel data = new DataModel();

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    if (b == null) {
      RecyclerView dataView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
      dataView.setAdapter(new RecyclerAdapter(this, new LinearLayoutManager(this), data.getItemList()));
    }
  }
}
```

After you set things up this way, whenever you update `itemlist`, you should be seeing the changes automatically reflected. If not, call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I have 2 ArrayList. One (dbList) is used to retrieve all the data stored in the DB, and the other one (itemList) is used to filter some of the items in dbList. I don't really understand how it works and how should I implement it. Could you please explain more in detail? Thank you so much. I will update the code in DB.